# Application_Error renders page on local host but not on production(www)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, global-asax

I have an Application_Error which renders an error page:

```
    private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        // A good location for any error logging, otherwise, do it inside of the error controller.

        Response.Clear();
        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();

        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

        // Clear the error, otherwise, we will always get the default error page.
        Server.ClearError();

        routeData.Values.Add("id", httpException.GetHttpCode());
        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

        // Call the controller with the route
        IController errorController = new ErrorController();
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));


    }
```

works on my local machine seamlessly. when i push it to production, it renders the regular asp 404 page instead of the page which the controller is supposed to server.

Even on production server, when i use `localhost` instead of `www` it works.

i should add that i have no configrations in `web.config` for customerrors. i tried turning them off and that didnt help either.

to me it seems like it is the url that is causing this but cant figure out why/how.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Dumb question: do you have a way of making sure that your `settings.DevelopmentMode` is returning the expected value in PRODUCTION?  Sometimes I ignore the simplest things...

Comment: @DavidTansey that is set false on production. It is hardcoded in the application and always returns false.

Comment: Have you turned on detailed errors in iis?  that sometimes replaces your error messages with the standard page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Application_Error method please try adding this...

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```